# How to fix user assignment to dynamic groups in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to assign users to a dynamic group in Azure AD.
The users are synced from our on-prem AD to the cloud.

For the dynamic group I'm using an extension attribute which is filled with roles.
These roles are filled in to the attribute by a script.

Now I have the strange behaviour:

- Users that have the attribute filled by myself are synced correctly to the dynamic group.
- Users that have the attribute filled by the script are not in the dynamic group, eventhough the role is correctly assigned.

In the pictures you can see 2 different users with the exactly same attribute, but only the user which was not done with the script is correctly added in the group.
Can someone help me with this issue?

[image]

[image]

I need to fix this, because the attribute has to be filled for 300+ users.
The assignment to the dynamic group needs to work with the script.

**Additional, here is my script which I was using:**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create a new Windows Form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Value Selector"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1000, 1000)

# Create a FlowLayoutPanel to display available values
$flowLayoutPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
$flowLayoutPanel.Dock = "Fill"
$flowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = "TopDown"
$flowLayoutPanel.WrapContents = $true
$flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = $true
$flowLayoutPanel.Padding = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10) # Add padding around each checkbox

# Define available values
$availableValues = "Sales manager", "Sales administrator", "Issue manager", "Change manager", "Document author", "Document reviewer", "Line manager", "HR responsible", "ICT manager", "ICT supporter"

# Sort the values alphabetically
$availableValues = $availableValues | Sort-Object

# Create checkboxes for each available value
foreach ($value in $availableValues) {
    $checkBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $checkBox.Text = $value
    $checkBox.AutoSize = $true
    $checkBox.Padding = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5) # Add padding around checkbox text
    $checkBox.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right # Anchor checkbox to top, left, and right
    $flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($checkBox)
}

# Add the FlowLayoutPanel to the form
$form.Controls.Add($flowLayoutPanel)

# Create a ComboBox to select a user from Active Directory
$userComboBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$userComboBox.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList
$userComboBox.Dock = "Top"
$userComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name"
$userComboBox.ValueMember = "DistinguishedName"
$userComboBox.DataSource = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName | Sort-Object Name # Sort the users alphabetically

# Add the ComboBox to the form
$form.Controls.Add($userComboBox)

# Create a Button to clear the selection of checkboxes
$buttonClearSelection = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonClearSelection.Text = "Clear Selection"
$buttonClearSelection.Dock = "Bottom"
$buttonClearSelection.Add_Click({
    foreach ($checkBox in $flowLayoutPanel.Controls) {
        $checkBox.Checked = $false
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($buttonClearSelection)

# Create a Button to generate the selected string and write it to the user's extension attribute
$buttonGenerate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonGenerate.Text = "Generate and Write to Extension Attribute"
$buttonGenerate.Dock = "Bottom"
$buttonGenerate.Add_Click({
    # Get the selected user and values
    $selectedUser = $userComboBox.SelectedItem.DistinguishedName
    $selectedValues = $flowLayoutPanel.Controls | Where-Object { $_.Checked }
    $selectedString = ($selectedValues.Text -join ', ')

    # Write the selected string to the user's extension attribute
    Set-ADUser -Identity $selectedUser -Replace @{extensionAttribute10=$selectedString}

    # Show a message box with the result
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Selected values: $selectedString`r`n`r`nGenerated string has been written to the user's extension attribute.", "Result", "OK", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
})
$form.Controls.Add($buttonGenerate)

# Create a Button to clear the extensionAttribute10
$buttonClear = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonClear.Text = "Clear Extension Attribute"
$buttonClear.Dock = "Bottom"
$buttonClear.Add_Click({
    # Get the selected user and clear the extensionAttribute10
    $selectedUser = $userComboBox.SelectedItem.DistinguishedName
    Set-ADUser -Identity $selectedUser -Clear extensionAttribute10

    # Show a message box with the result
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Extension attribute has been cleared.", "Result", "OK", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
})
$form.Controls.Add($buttonClear)

# Show the form and start the event loop
$form.ShowDialog()

# Dispose of the form when it is closed
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: Look at Ad-User : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#examples  I think you need to add a SearchBase.  Try running just Ad-User until you get the right options.

Comment: Well the script is working, as you see in my screenshots both users contain the same roles in the attribute. But only the one which I filled by myself and not with the script gets synced into the dynamic group. To other one generated by the script had the correct roles in Azure AD but the user is not shown in the dynamic group. What could be the issue?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-troubleshooting?force_isolation=true

Comment: It looks like you want to do `$selected = ($flowLayoutPanel.Controls | Where-Object { $_.Checked }).Text -join ', '` and then `Set-ADUser -Identity $selectedUser -Replace @{extensionAttribute10=[string]$selected}`